# Redundant cell in GridPane JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, gridpanel

I'm new in JavaFX, I would like to create a Grid example with some columns and rows. The grid as below:
- first row: the first cell (width = 100) occupies 1 column and the second cell (width = 200) occupies 2 column
- second row: the first (width = 200) cell occupies 2 column and the second cell (width = 100) occupies 1 column

But I don't know why there is a unexpected cell appears. As below image:

[image]

My code as below:

```
     // Label 1
     Label lbl1 = new Label("Label1");
     lbl1.setPrefWidth(100);
     lbl1.setStyle("-fx-border-style: solid; -fx-background-color: #80aaff; -fx-border-width: 0.25");
     // Label 2
     Label lbl2 = new Label("Label2");
     lbl2.setStyle("-fx-border-style: solid; -fx-background-color:#ff80bf; -fx-border-width: 0.25");
     lbl2.setPrefWidth(200);
     // Label 3
     Label lbl3 = new Label("Label3");
     lbl3.setPrefWidth(200);
     lbl3.setStyle("-fx-border-style: solid; -fx-background-color:#66ff99; -fx-border-width: 0.25");
     // Label 4
     Label lbl4 = new Label("Label4");
     lbl4.setPrefWidth(100);
     lbl4.setStyle("-fx-border-style: solid; -fx-background-color: #ffff66; -fx-border-width: 0.25");

     GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
     gridPane.setStyle("-fx-border-style: solid");

     // column 0, row 0, column span 1, row span 1
     gridPane.add(lbl1, 0, 0, 1, 1);
     // column 1, row 0, column span 2, row span 1
     gridPane.add(lbl2, 1, 0, 2, 1);
     // column 0, row 1, column span 1, row span 1
     gridPane.add(lbl3, 0, 1, 2, 1);
     // column 2, row 1, column span 2, row span 1
     gridPane.add(lbl4, 2, 1, 1, 1);
```

Can anyone point out my problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I checked article, but I don't know what my question's format wrong and how I have to edit. Could you please tell me clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculation of the prefered width for the `GridPane` with column spans/overlapping columns often doesn't work quite as expected. The "cell" you see is the background of the `GridPane` not covered by any child.

To avoid the `GridPane` from becoming too large, set the column widths via `ColumnConstraints`:

```
// Label 1
Label lbl1 = new Label("Label1");
lbl1.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
lbl1.setStyle("-fx-border-style: solid; -fx-background-color: #80aaff; -fx-border-width: 0.25");
// Label 2
Label lbl2 = new Label("Label2");
lbl2.setStyle("-fx-border-style: solid; -fx-background-color:#ff80bf; -fx-border-width: 0.25");
lbl2.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
// Label 3
Label lbl3 = new Label("Label3");
lbl3.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
lbl3.setStyle("-fx-border-style: solid; -fx-background-color:#66ff99; -fx-border-width: 0.25");
// Label 4
Label lbl4 = new Label("Label4");
lbl4.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
lbl4.setStyle("-fx-border-style: solid; -fx-background-color: #ffff66; -fx-border-width: 0.25");

GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();

ColumnConstraints constraints = new ColumnConstraints(100);
gridPane.getColumnConstraints().addAll(constraints, constraints, constraints);

gridPane.setStyle("-fx-border-style: solid");

// column 0, row 0, column span 1, row span 1
gridPane.add(lbl1, 0, 0);
// column 1, row 0, column span 2, row span 1
gridPane.add(lbl2, 1, 0, 2, 1);
// column 0, row 1, column span 1, row span 1
gridPane.add(lbl3, 0, 1, 2, 1);
// column 2, row 1, column span 2, row span 1
gridPane.add(lbl4, 2, 1);
```

This doesn't prevent the empty "space" from reappearing when the window is resized though. To use the same size for all columns regardless of the width of the `GridPane` use `percentWidth`:

```
ColumnConstraints constraints = new ColumnConstraints();
constraints.setPercentWidth(100d/3d);
gridPane.setPrefWidth(300);
```

Comment: Hi fabian,
In SWT, I can create a layout with specified column (ex: 100 column) by 
GridLayout(100, true), size of column base on layout's size (layout will be fill out horizontal) and number of column
Can I make this in JavaFX?

Comment: The JavaFX equivalent would be `int columnCount = 100; ColumnConstraints constraints = new ColumnConstraints(); constraints.setPercentWidth(100d / columnCount); for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) gridPane.getColumnConstraints().add(constraints);`